# How to prevent spam comments?

Tags: plugins, comments

I have NoSpamMX plugin installed. I was not getting spam comments for a long time. But now I am getting a lot of spam comments especially in one post.

What is the reason that there is such a lot of spams only to that post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 for akismet

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cookies-for-comments/

Is also amazing.  Akismet is great at catching spam, but adding cookies for comments is awesome.  It stops a lot of the auto-posted spam.  (Which most of it is)

Cookies for comments will stop the comment before it even gets to you.  Akismet was catching 50 spams a day for me.  But once I added CFC, I only get maybe 1 comment a week for akismet to deal with.  The two combined are great

Answer (score 4):

Akismet is a great plugin to prevent spam.
It works great on my blogs - not one single spamcomment have made it through, yet.

Comment: Just remember, even with Akismet you'll still get spam ... it will just be marked as such and hidden.

Comment: true! However, I would rather have it marked as spam and not shown, than deleted by default.
The main thing must be: not to have it shown on the live website.

Answer (score 2):

I combined Askimet with a plugin called "Growmap Anti Spambot Plugin" and it has been working well. The second just adds a checkbox above the "Publish Comment" button with the label "This comment is not a spam". Then, the user has an extra click to do but the spams are reduced considerably.

Answer (score 2):

rgksugan: 
Ordinarily I wouldn't just plug my company, but we just this week released a WordPress plugin to protect against spam, profanity, racism, hate speech, violence, threats, and more.

It's currently in a free Beta release at http://impermium.com/wordpress. Check it out; I believe it can fix your problem and would love to know what you think.

Comment: I found Part 3 the most interesting aspect of your Impermium service https://automod.impermium.com/console/wordpress/howitworks#3 Good luck! It seems like a promising service if effective!

Comment: Thanks, Feral, kind of you to provide feedback. Yes, Impermium classifies content into a wide variety of categories, enabling clients to take policy action based on fine-grained controls.

Answer (score 0):

I added this below code in my .htaccess file to stop spambots. It's working well for me.

```
# Flood secure on wp-comments-post.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*blogginger.* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```